# `stack test` doesn't read from stdin

Tags: haskell, stdin, haskell-stack

I'm using Stack Version 2.7.3 on OS X. With this simple code:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
    l <- getLine
    putStrLn l
```

This is in the default stack project template, just modifying `Test.hs`.

Building and running with `stack test` results in the error message `<stdin>: hGetLine: end of file`. Everything else (including output) works just fine. If I find the executable in `.stack-work` and run it manually, it runs perfectly.

Is there some flag I must enable to let stack read from stdin? There is an unrelated issue on GitHub and on this site, but the problem there is with docker. I am just using a plain stack installation here.

Comment: How does that code even compile? It looks like you’ve missed a line `main = do`.

Comment: @bradrn Yes, that was written in a bit of haste. I lost a line in the middle.

Comment: Why do you want to read from stdin in your tests? I don't think it is possible to do that.

Comment: @Noughtmare Ah thanks, so `stack test` isn't meant to deal with IO right? Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Noughtmare I'm trying to make the program pause for me to inspect the output in the middle. It suffices for me to know that it isn't designed to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running tests it seems stdin is immediately closed, so running `getLine` will throw an exception. However, I could not find any documentation to confirm this.

You could quickly move the test in the `package.yaml` file from the `tests:` section to the `executables:` section. Then you can run it with `stack run <your-test>`. That way you can debug your tests more easily.

With cabal this is even easier because you can run test suites as if they are executables with `cabal run <your-test>`.